# Highcharts - heatmap is overlapping

Tags: highcharts

I cant get my highcharts heatmap to get to work properly. There is overlapping when lot of series data. How to resolve it? Series are dynamic, date range can be a few days, and even a few years.

[image]

[jsfiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/4v6A5/)

```
{
chart: {
    type: 'heatmap',
        width: 455,
        height: 299,
        marginLeft: 85,
        marginRight: 15,
        style: {
        fontFamily: 'genius200'
    }
},

title: {
    text: ''
},

colorAxis: {
    min: 0,
        minColor: '#FFFFFF',
        maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
},
xAxis: {
    type: 'category'
},

yAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
        labels: {
        formatter: function() {
            return Highcharts.dateFormat("%b %e", this.value);
        }
    }
},
legend: {
    enabled: false
},

plotOptions: {
    area: {
        fillColor: {
            linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1},
            stops: [
                [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
            ]
        },
        lineWidth: 1,
            marker: {
            enabled: false
        },
        shadow: false,
            states: {
            hover: {
                lineWidth: 1
            }
        },
        threshold: null
    }
},

series: [{
    data: series,
    rowsize: 3600000 * 24,
    borderWidth: 1,
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        color: 'black',
        style: {
            textShadow: 'none',
            HcTextStroke: null
        }
    }
}]
```

Comment: Well.. and what you want to do? I would change chart's height according to number of points: http://jsfiddle.net/4v6A5/1/

Comment: I cant change height. Can I achieve the same result without changing height? Can I zoom `y axis`? For example, If I zoom out I'll have values grouped by dates, in the boxes summed in one box?

Comment: Yes, you can set min and max for yAxis. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/4v6A5/2/ Grouping by dates etc isn't supported by heatmap.